# I am trying to import React-PDF but when I try to render the component it npm stalls and never renders my project

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-pdf

When I save the component when importing: import {Document, Page} from 'react-pdf'; the project just stalls and npm takes more and more of my cpu overheating my computer. What could be the issue?

[package-lock.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stoCm.png)

Comment: Have you narrowed it down to that file that's importing it being the cause of the stall? If so, can you add the whole component?